# Telerik HTML5 Viewer Access Denied

Tags: html, telerik

I periodically receive an access denied error on a Telerik trdx report surfaced with the html5 viewer. I've given everyone permissions to the web site as well as the temp folder used by the cache.  I have a report that calls a stored proc that takes a date and userid as params.  Many people will hit the report with the same date likely at the same time.  The report also has a sql query sourcing a subreport but I don't think that matters for this discussion.  Most of the time the report works fine.  However some people, some times, will get the error below - the last 11 or so digits might change.  Sometimes if they pick another day for the report - the report works.  As far as I can tell, each report viewed for a particular day creates a folder for the cache...and that folder could be reused by other users for the same day.  It also looks like Telerik sets the permissions to the cache folder for this instance of the report to the user running the report.  So if User A selects 2/20/14 and User B select 2/20/14 at the same time, Telerik wants to use the same folder...and the first user is the only one with permissions.  I could be totally off but this is how it looks to me.  Any clarification on how to stabilize the reporting would be appreciated.

An error has occurred.
Access to the path '7.2.13.1016_135907-aa13' is denied

Answer (score 1):

As an option please try to create different caches for different users using CacheFactory.CreateFileCache Method (String).

So it could be something like this:

```
 public class ReportController : ReportsControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public ReportController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    protected override IReportResolver CreateReportResolver()
    {
        return new CustomReportResolver();
    }

    protected override ICache CreateCache()
    {
        return Telerik.Reporting.Services.Engine.CacheFactory.CreateFileCache(String.Format("{0}\{1}", cachePath, windowsUserService.GetUser());
    }
```

}